# Fluent nhibernate - Design issue

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

What would be the best way to implement fluent-nhibernate regarding project architecture?

I have two projects at the moment one for the domain layer and the other is the persistance layer.  My problem is that when trying to configure nhibernate I get a circular reference.

The domain references the persistance layer but how do I get the configuration to work without having to reference the domain in the persistance layer i.e. the product class in this line AddFromAssemblyOf()?

Currently my configuration is like this.

```
return Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(c =>         c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("DisillStoreConnectionString")))
                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Product>())) 
                .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: I don't really see why your domain project should reference the persistence project... Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: Hi Tomas, I have a reference to the persistence project from the domain project so that I can retrieve data via the repository i.e. something like this:
 
public IEnumerable<Product> GetProductsByID(int Id)
{
  genericRepository.Get<Product>(id);
}

Is this a design flaw?  Are there better ways to implement the domain model and fluent-nhibernate?




Is this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want your Fluent config class in your persistence project with your `ClassMap` classes, not your domain models.

Using your code sample, you'd want to `AddFromAssemblyOf` on your `Map` class and not your `Model` class.  See:

```
return Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(
                 c =>
                   c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("DisillStoreConnectionString")))
                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<ProductMap>())) 
                .BuildSessionFactory();
```

This way, your domain project doesn't need to reference your persistence project.

Comment: JMP,  thanks for the reply.  Would you not have the same problem as the ProductMap referencing Product (Model)?

public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product>

How can you populate the domain object without referencing the persistance layer from your domain layer?

Comment: Your domain objects will need to be marked public in their own assembly.  Also, your domain objects will not populate themselves, nHibernate will populate them based on information it gets from your configuration class.  The domain project need not reference your persistence project at all.